# using ES6 npm module (webpack) in the front end

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm making an `npm` module using `ES6` syntax (`imports`, `exports` etc) via `webpack`.

When I try to initialize an instance of the exported class in the frontend to test it, it isn't working and I've got a feeling it's to do with what `CommonJS` exports return vs `ES6` exports.

**example.js**

```
export default class Example { ....
```

**example-after-webpack-stuff.js**

```
var Example = (function() ....
```

**demo.js**

```
var example = new Example();
```

**demo.html**

```
<script src="../example-after-webpack-stuff.js"></script>
<script src="demo.js"></script>
```

I receive the following:

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Example is not a function

EDIT

Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/example.js',
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/example.js",
        library: "Example",
        libraryTarget: "var"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: It won't work like that. You have to bundle the whole thing and use the single js file in the script tag.

Comment: @kabirbaidhya How? example-after-webpack-stuff is the npm module and demo.js is a custom file, something a user would make themselves

Comment: Okay, all the files you write in ES6 that depends upon one another needs to be bundled using webpack/browserify to produce a single bundle.js or something like that. And that file is what you use in the <script> tag. Okay, check this example repo. I've done it here: https://github.com/kabirbaidhya/ReduxTodoApp

Comment: @Felix I already have the `library` option set to `Example` and `libraryTarget` set to `var` but it still doesn't work

Comment: So `var Example = (function() ....` is at the beginning of the compiled file? Then I don't see what the issue is. Of course we can't do much with an incomplete example. Please post all the relevant code / configuration. *"I already have the `library` option set to `Example`"* Why didn't you say that from the beginning?

Comment: @FelixKling updated and yes it is at the beginning of the included file

Comment: If you look at what the function returns, you should be able to figure out why it doesn't work. I can only assume that because you are using ES6 modules, the exported value is an object. `Example.default()` might work (instead of `Example()`). If that's the case then I recommend to use a CommonJS module as entry point and do `module.exports = require('./example').default;`. Let me if that's the issue.

Comment: @FelixKling Hey, I was being stupid - that is indeed the issue. I wanted to use all ES6 but the classes seem to export an object with the function as one of it's properties. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since babel 6, `export default class Example` will be compiled to `exports.default = Example`. While in Babel 5, it will be compiled to `exports = Example`. So you code will run without error using babel 5.

In babel 6, you can use CommonJS way `module.exports`:

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
}

module.exports = Example;
```

Or you can use `babel-plugin-add-module-exports` to change babel 6's behavior.

```
npm install babel-plugin-add-module-exports --save-dev
```

Add it in webpack.config.js:

```
loaders: [
  {
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015'],
      plugins: ['add-module-exports']
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The plugin was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! (Shame they did that in Babel 6 :s)